# Align text below a div on regular width intervals

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I've created an Angular directive in which a user can change certain settings depending on the time of the day. Below is a picture of what I already have:

[image: Unfinished element]

I'd like to add kind of "ticks" that accurately represent the time on x-axis of the div to show the user what he's doing, like in the picture below:

[image: Finished concept]

These would have to be at exact 1/24ths of the div above it. I can set the div width to a fixed number if it helps. I'd also want the key times shown like in the picture. What would be the best way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

I am just going to list in theory what could work, it's up to you to try it out. I would try the following steps (my solutions are not traditional, but could work):

1. For the ticks, I could try add 24 spaced letter 'l' or capital I (which ever would create a tick with spaces in between, set the line-height and font to the length you want, bold the relevant ticks and then add text-align:justify.

Or for a more traditional approach you could go for a row with 24 columns each of 1/24th width using css, float the columns and add border.

2. For the numbers I would add another row div with the number of columns equal to the number of time you want to show-1, the last column having the extra time to show at the right corner.
3. I would add each time as a strong element and add position relative to the parent column, and position absolute to the strong element positioning them left -10 or so which makes them appear like above.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox will work here..and the upper div can be any size.

Just add a wrapper and let that determine the width.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/EyNrOB)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 80%;
}
.object {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  width: 25%;
  background: lightblue;
}
.ticks {
  height: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.tick {
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
}

.tick.major {
  background:red;
  width:2px;
  }
.time {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="object">
  <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="ticks">
    <div class="tick major">
      <div class="time">00:00</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tick"></div>
    <div class="tick"></div>
    <div class="tick"></div>
    <div class="tick"></div>
    <div class="tick"></div>
    <div class="tick major">
      <div class="time">06:00</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tick"></div>
    <div class="tick"></div>
    <div class="tick"></div>
    <div class="tick"></div>
    <div class="tick"></div>
    <div class="tick major">
      <div class="time">12:00</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tick"></div>
    <div class="tick"></div>
    <div class="tick"></div>
    <div class="tick"></div>
    <div class="tick"></div>
    <div class="tick major">
      <div class="time">18:00</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tick"></div>
    <div class="tick"></div>
    <div class="tick"></div>
    <div class="tick"></div>
    <div class="tick"></div>
    <div class="tick major">
      <div class="time">00:00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am providing basic idea of how you can achieve your goal

```css
.time_interval,.line{
   width:100%;
  }
  .line div{
    color:#000;
       float: left;
       height: 5px;
       width: 4%;
       text-align:center;
  } 
  .line .b{
   font-weight:bold;
   color:red;
  }
  .timer div{
   float: left;
   text-align:center;
   height: 5px;
   width: 4%;
   padding-top:15px
  }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
 
    </head>
    <body>
 <div class="line">
  <div class="b">|</div><div>|</div>
  <div>|</div><div>|</div>
  <div>|</div><div>|</div>
  <div class="b">|</div><div>|</div>
  <div>|</div><div>|</div>
  <div>|</div><div>|</div>
  <div class="b">|</div><div>|</div>
  <div>|</div><div>|</div>
  <div>|</div><div>|</div>
  <div class="b">|</div><div>|</div>
  <div>|</div><div>|</div>
  <div>|</div><div>|</div>
  <div class="b">|</div>
 </div>
 <div class="timer">
  <div>00:00</div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div>
  <div>06:00</div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div>
  <div>12:00</div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div>
  <div>18:00</div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div>
  <div>00:00</div>
 </div>
    </body>    
</html>
```